# Running a test with two invocations of the same fixture (but with different parameters)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm writing a test suite in Pytest.  I have a fixture that looks something like this:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["cpu", "gpu"])
def device(request):
    return request.param
```

This is because I want my code to work identically on both CPUs and GPUs.  (*This fact is technically not relevant to my question, but I wanted to give a practical example of my use case.*) All other fixtures representing device-independent code depend on `device`, like so:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def data(device):
    return LoadData(path, device)
```

So far so good.  Any test that uses `load_data` is called twice:

```
def test_data_is_loaded(data):
    assert data.success
```

But here's my problem: **What if I want to compare the output of two different parametrizations of the same fixture?**

```
def test_devices_load_same_amount_of_data(data_cpu, data_gpu):
    assert len(data_cpu) == len(data_gpu)

def test_gpu_is_faster_than_cpu(data_cpu, data_gpu):
    cpu_start = time.time()
    data_cpu.process()
    cpu_duration = time.time() - cpu_start

    gpu_start = time.time()
    data_gpu.process()
    gpu_duration = time.time() - gpu_start

    assert gpu_duration < cpu_duration
```

I'd like to be able to do something like that *without splitting `data` into multiple fixtures*; I tried that already, but it made my test code error-prone and hard to change (because there was a lot of useless duplication).

It's okay if I have to write new fixtures, hooks, or markers.  They just have to be for the purpose of *reducing* code duplication instead of *adding* it.

It's also okay if there's a third-party plugin that does this.

Comment: I believe they are going to provide same output but if you are trying to do same operation via CPU & GPU and want to find which method is better ?If so use python `timeit` method to measure execution time it will help you conclude which is better method for you.

Comment: The fact that I'm using a GPU is technically irrelevant to this question; I just wanted to provide an illustrative example of why I want to do this.  Also, you might believe that the CPU and GPU will provide the same results, but I'd certainly like to be sure of that (hence my test cases).

Comment: You are trying to prove, I am using "this" because "this" works better than "that" in this case ? Still you can use timeit module.

Comment: Could you create fixtures called `gpu` and `cpu` that directly return whatever `data` currently returns for those cases, and then have `data` do something like `if request.param == "gpu": return gpu()` and likewise for `cpu`?  That way `data` would still exist as a single feature, but you could also access the two separate versions directly for cases where you need to do so.

Comment: @BrenBarn No, because then I'd have to create fixtures that look like `something_cpu` and `something_gpu`, which I'm trying to avoid in the first place.  I just want to access fixture parametrizations that already exist.

Comment: @JesseTG: Why is that a problem?  What I'm saying is that you can have fixtures called `something_gpu` and `something_cpu`, but *also* still have `data`, which calls them and returns what they return (depending on `request.param` as it does now).  Then all your existing code can continue to use `data`, but now will additionally have the option of calling one of the underlying `something_*` fixtures if a test needs both separately in the same run.